# How can I run a Pipescript code in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed on my Mac the Pipescript language 2.1 version.

I have created a small Pipescript code (.pps file) in VSCode :

```
depends http
depends json

#skip_on_error
val temperature = http::get("api.weather.com/temperature")

if temperature > 30
    val adjustedTemp = temperature - 5
    val result = adjustedTemp * 2
    output::println("Final result: " + result)
else
    output::println("Not Temperature enough for calculations.")
end
```

Now I have installed the Pipescript extension in VSCode but I don't know how to run it.Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to create a package using `npm init` then install Nodemon:

```js
npm install nodemon
```

> nodemon is a tool that helps develop Node.js based applications by automatically restarting the node application when file changes in the directory are detected.

Now just add this line inside the script object in your *package.json* file:

```json
"dev": "nodemon file_name.pps"
```

This will execute the "*file_name.pps*" file each time you run

```
npm run dev
```

and keep tracking changes